# How to show git colors on Zsh?

Tags: git, zsh

I recently started to use Zsh as my default shell. One thing that I like in git is the colors, for example, the `git status` and `git diff` used to have colors (additions in green, and deletions in red).

Now with Zsh it is all white (the default color). How can I put colors on git outputs in Zsh?
Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`git config --global color.diff auto`
`git config --global color.status auto`

Answer (score 17):

Migore,

My `.gitconfig` is set up like this:

```
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = auto
  branch = auto
[color "status"]
  changed = yellow
  added = green
  untracked = red
```

Comment: If anyone is thinking of placing where to put it, it should be inside ~/.gitconfig file in your home dir. At least in my case.

Answer (score 13):

I was searching for the solution in the zsh side. But it turned out that git has a solution for that.
Just add this to your .gitconfig file

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

Answer (score 1):

If see escape code like "ESC[33mcommit" in the text instead of colors, try setting the PAGER variable in your .zshrc to something like this:

```
#export PAGER=${PAGER:-less}
export PAGER='less -r'
```